# How to pass two values got from a function to the corresponding variable

Tags: java

This is my getSecret function used to get name and secret from AWSSecretsManager

```
public static void getSecret() {

        String secretName = "test-eg-gtp-tax-engine-adapter-mvp";
        String region = "us-west-2";

        // Create a Secrets Manager client
        AWSSecretsManager client  = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).build();
        GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest().withSecretId(secretName);
        GetSecretValueResult getSecretValueResult = null;

        getSecretValueResult = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);
        System.out.println("name  " + getSecretValueResult.getName());
        System.out.println("secret:  " + getSecretValueResult.getSecretString());
    }
```

I would like to pass these two values to another function's corresponding variable(name, secret), how can I do that, how should I change the return type of getSecret() function?

Comment: Maybe to String [] array ?

Comment: Why is Kotlin tagged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to create a class representing the `name` and `secret`

```
class SecretInfo  {

    String name;
    String secret;
}
```

which you could then return from your method.

---

As @Typhon mentioned in the comments, you could also just return an array, but that seems less explicit and safe.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in the comments you can change the return type of method to array if you want to return multiple values

```
public static String [] getSecret() {

        String secretName = "test-eg-gtp-tax-engine-adapter-mvp";
        String region = "us-west-2";

        // Create a Secrets Manager client
        AWSSecretsManager client  = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).build();
        GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest().withSecretId(secretName);
        GetSecretValueResult getSecretValueResult = null;

        getSecretValueResult = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);
        System.out.println("name  " + getSecretValueResult.getName());
        System.out.println("secret:  " + getSecretValueResult.getSecretString());
        
        return new String[]{getSecretValueRequest.getName(),getSecretValueRequest.getSecretString};
    }
```

---

Or as @Henry said

```
class SecretInfo  {

    String name;
    String secret;
}
```

then in your method

```
public static SecretInfo getSecret() {

        String secretName = "test-eg-gtp-tax-engine-adapter-mvp";
        String region = "us-west-2";

        // Create a Secrets Manager client
        AWSSecretsManager client  = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).build();
        GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest().withSecretId(secretName);
        GetSecretValueResult getSecretValueResult = null;

        getSecretValueResult = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);
        System.out.println("name  " + getSecretValueResult.getName());
        System.out.println("secret:  " + getSecretValueResult.getSecretString());

        return new SecretInfo(getSecretValueResult.getName(),getSecretValueResult.getSecretString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Model class having required properties

public class Secret {
    
        private String name;
        private String secretString;
        
        public Secret(String name,String secretString){
            this.name=name;
            this.secretString=secretString;
        }
        // setter getter
    }
    
    // Return type is of Secret

    public static Secret getSecret() {
    
            String secretName = "test-eg-gtp-tax-engine-adapter-mvp";
            String region = "us-west-2";
    
            // Create a Secrets Manager client
            AWSSecretsManager client  = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).build();
            GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest().withSecretId(secretName);
            GetSecretValueResult getSecretValueResult = null;
    
            getSecretValueResult = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);
            System.out.println("name  " + getSecretValueResult.getName());
            System.out.println("secret:  " + getSecretValueResult.getSecretString());
    
            // return new object of Secret
            return new Secret(getSecretValueResult.getName(),getSecretValueResult.getSecretString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using kotlin but if you are you can use `Pair<String, String>` as @Alex.T suggested and you can improve readability of the code by using  [type aliases](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-aliases.html):

```
typealias SecretData = Pair<String, String>

fun getSecret(): SecretData {
    //...//
    return getSecretValueResult.getName() to getSecretValueResult.getSecretString()
}
```

but I would prefer data class:

```
data class SecretData(val name: String, val secret: String)
```